# oracle SQL subquery: using the minimum but getting all columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
                       MIN(A.price)  CustomerID     TripID travelby
```

---

```
                                 25  x05               66 train
                                 66  x07               21 train
                                100  x07               12 train
```

Trying to figure this one out. the above results is from a query of 2 tables. However, I need to modify it so that it gives me the result of min price with all of its 4 columns.

this was my original sql:

(select min(price)
from trips a, customers b
where a.tripid = b.tripid and c.travelmode = 'train')

I can only get the row with 25, but that is only if i request the price column. How would you go about this, but get all columns? Thank you for all input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   trips a
         INNER JOIN customers b
         ON ( a.tripid = b.tripid )
  WHERE  travelby = 'train'
  ORDER BY price ASC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT price,
         CustomerID,
         a.TripID,
         travelby,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY price ASC ) AS rn
  FROM   trips a
         INNER JOIN customers b
         ON ( a.tripid = b.tripid )
  WHERE  travelby = 'train'
  ORDER BY price ASC
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT MIN( price ) AS price,
       MIN( CustomerID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY price, ROWNUM ) AS CustomerID,
       MIN( a.TripID   ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY price, ROWNUM ) AS TripID,
       MIN( travelby   ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY price, ROWNUM ) AS travelby
FROM   trips a
       INNER JOIN customers b
       ON ( a.tripid = b.tripid )
WHERE  travelby = 'train'
```

Comment: Thank you MT0. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select . . .
from (select . . ., row_number() over (order by price desc) as seqnum
      from trips t join
           customers c
           on c.tripid = t.tripid and ?.travelmode = 'train'
     )
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your version of the query is quite confusing:

- Why is it surrounded by parentheses?
- What is `c.travelmode`?  You haven't defined the table alias `c`.
- Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the input. the parenthesis was there because i just copied it from another query within a query in sql developer. forgot to removed them. travelmode was actually meant as travelby.